# systemctl list-units for type target not behaving as expected

Tags: systemd, systemctl

Summary: 'systemctl list-units --type=target --all' does not always list targets that I've added

Detail:

I have a project that consists of several related daemons; let's call this project 'Foo.' The daemons are managed by systemd service units, and the services are grouped together for easier management in a target. I have 'production' and 'testing' deployments of projcet Foo. So, I've created foo_testing.target and foo_production.target under /etc/systemd/system.  In fact, I have this arrangement on a variety of physical hosts and VMs -- some have both production and testing, some have only one or the other.
I therefore need to be able to interrogate a given host as to what is installed and what is running.

Having reviewed the docs for systemd and systemctl I hit upon

```
systemctl list-units --type=target --all
```

This works fine for targets that are running. If production and/or testing is running it will reliably show up in the output of list-units.

The problem is stopped targets.  If I 'systemctl stop foo_testing.target' and immediately ask for the list of units, then foo_testing.target will be in the list (marked inactive).  But, if I leave the testing deployment stopped for a day or two, and then come back and do 'systemctl list-units --type=target --all' then foo_testing *won't* be in the list *at all*.

So, why does systemd 'forget' about my targets if they haven't been active for a while?

Here's the system info for the most problematic host:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
$ uname -a
Linux <redacted> 5.11.0-49-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 17:36:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$systemctl --version
systemd 247 (247.3-3ubuntu3.7)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

[Edit]
As requested, here's the output of 'systemctl cat'

```
$ systemctl cat "foo*.target"
# /etc/systemd/system/foo_testing.target
[Unit]
Description=Foo Testing Environment
AllowIsolate=no
Wants=serv1_testing.service serv2_testing.service serv3_testing.service

# /etc/systemd/system/foo_production.target
[Unit]
Description=Foo Production Environment
AllowIsolate=no
Wants=serv1_prod.service serv2_prod.service serv3_prod.service
```

Note, though, that this output does not change.  It is the behavior of 'systemctl list-units' that changes.

[Edit 2] Q: Any non-target systemd units with matching base name installed on the system?

A: such units do exist -- owing to my naming scheme.  Is this potentially part of the explanation?

Comment: Please upgrade to a **[supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) OS release**, Ubuntu 21.04 is dangerous after [lacking security upgrades since 2022-01-20](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html). Any non-target systemd units with matching base name installed on the system? (If in doubt, just show the output of `find /etc/systemd /run/systemd -iname "*foo*"`)

Comment: well -- 17 whole minutes before somebody unhelpfully suggested that I reinstall the OS.  Longer than expected, actually. Does it never occur that I might not have approval from (mis)management to go reinstalling the entire OS at the drop of a hat?

Comment: While not relevant in this case because a still-supported release is also affected, [this site](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) generally focuses on system management in a business environment. The sort of environment where not today, but two years ago a decision was made to move all software support deadline further out than the expected time to get upgrades budgeted, planned approved & done, possibly by switching to LTS releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list-units` cannot be expected to report consistently on inactive units:

> list-units [PATTERN…]
>
> List units that systemd **currently has in memory**. This includes units
> that are either referenced directly or through a dependency, units
> that are pinned by applications programmatically, or units that were
> active in the past and have failed.

from `man systemctl`, emphasis mine.

The command seems more geared towards letting a human see *the unit state at a glance*, and must be expected to forget about units no longer needed, e.g. after some unspecified time, or on daemon reload or reexec.

If in a script you need the running *status*  of a unit, use `systemctl is-active` (for state `is-enabled`, for file existence: `list-unit-files`, ..) which produce consistent results, no matter the in-memory status.

Comment: OK -- that does explain the behavior.  I'll accept your answer on that basis.  However, I still don't have something that will let me use systemctl to answer the question "which targets are on this host?"  For now, I can use 'systemctl is-active' and ask specifically about production and testing.  But, in the future, maybe I want 3 environments (experimental, testing, production) or 4, or more... Is it really the case that the best way is 'ls /etc/systemd/system | grep target' ?

Comment: @KevinPowell see edit, there are additional commands depending on what you need (running status, enablement state, unit file existence, ..)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  Turns out what I wanted was probably "systemctl list-unit-files --type=target" all along.  The way list-units is currently documented (particularly when combined with the docs for --all : which says "When listing units with list-units, also show inactive units...") seems to leave a lot of room for misinterpretation.

Comment: From what I remember, it used to be that systemd kept unit files in memory for quite a bit longer after they went inactive (though still not loading all of them proactively), so the documentation might be a leftover from that time.